# How to overcome "can't login into database requested by the user"?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Hello I just publish an app that require a database with Sql Server 2008 and Visual C# 2010. It works really well on my laptop but when I try it on another laptop I got this error !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZGJ8.png

I use SQL Authentication method to grant user to read and write to the database but it is useless, this is my connection string

```
stringkoneksi = @"Server = .\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                        "Database = UGsimplify;" + 
                        "Integrated Security = false;" +
                        "User ID = 'userdefined';" +
                        "Password = 'blablabla'";
```

do you have any step by step to make it works on another laptop?

Comment: the connectionString might be slightly different for the other machine. make sure the database has the same connectionString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
stringkoneksi =   @"Data Source=myServerAddress\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=UGsimplify;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword";
```

Configure your SQL server security as sql server and windows authentication mode.

To set up SQL Server and Widows Authentication Mode.

1. Connect to you SQL Server Instance
2. Right Click the go to properties
3. Choose Security on Select a Page Container
4. Then Choose SQL Server and Widows Authentication Mode on Server Authentication.
5. Click OK

Make sure your laptop(Server) SQL Server instance is running.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you will need to do is change your connection string so it uses the server name rather than . (LOCALHOST). For example, change your connection string to:

stringkoneksi = @"Server = [SERVERNAME]\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                        "Database = UGsimplify;" + 
                        "Integrated Security = false;" +
                        "User ID = 'userdefined';" +
                        "Password = 'blablabla'";

(Replace [SERVERNAME] with the name of the computer that is hosting your database.)

You will also need to ensure that the computer acting as your database server has the appropriate security settings to allow remote database connections (firewall settings, etc).

HTH!

Comment: Thank you. But are there any chances to attach my sql server database, so I don't need a remote connection?

Comment: Apologies, I thought you wanted to access the same database from both machines. If you have SQL Server installed on your other computer you can take a backup of the database and restore it to the SQL Server instance on your other computer. You will need to make sure a database login has been created with the correct username, password, and roles, and is mapped to the appropriate database.

Comment: yes but can I do it in sql server 2008 configuration tool without installing full sql server? I have included sql 2008 prerequisites on my app. Then if you suggest me to backup the database it means that i need to instal Sql server studio in every other computer, is that what you mean?

Comment: If you want to have a copy of the database on each computer that you are installing your application to, each computer will need to have SQL Server installed.

Comment: Then what version of Sql server that I should installed? Express or management tool?

Comment: For most purposes SQL Server Express should be fine. The management tool (SQL Server Management Studio) is an application that simplifies database management and administration. It is not a requirement of SQL Server though; you do not have to install it if you don't want to.

Comment: Can i get it automatically from prerequisites when I publish the app? Because it is automatically included when I publish it. Then if your answer is yes, where should I copy my database to another laptop?